# Lodash Method for Removing All Elements in Array After Match Found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, lodash

I have browsed over the Lodash docs quite a bit and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I want to know if Lodash has a method or simple combo of methods to remove all remaining elements in an array once a certain match has been detected, including the match itself.

For example:

```
let blogArray = ["check", "out", "my", "blog", "https", "someblog", "com"]
let matchingEl = "https"
_.doAThing(blogArray, matchingEl)
=> ["check", "out", "my", "blog"]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `once a certain match is detected `? What are you trying match against? Another array? A string?

Comment: It's 2018, you can do those things without any lodash with findIndex and splice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using indexOf and splice functions of an Array object. Below are the implementation using both Lodash and javascript functions

```
blogArray.splice(0,blogArray.indexOf(matchingEl))

_.slice(blogArray, 0, _.findIndex(blogArray, function(k){return k == matchingEl;})
```

Answer (score -1):

This is endearing to me

```
_.doAThing(blogArray)
```

Because it so boldly embodies a technique of programming called *wishful thinking* – it captures this idea that your program is as elegant as you want it to be; make a magic wand, wave it on some arguments, and your program works! And it does, we just have to write `_.doAThing`...

We can easily traverse an array using recursion. To design a recursive function, we have a *base* case, and *inductive* cases

- base case – `items` is empty, return an empty array
- inductive case 1 – `items` is *not* empty, therefore we have *at least one* element – if the `first` item matches `'https'`, we're done and there are no elements to follow; return empty array.
- inductive case 2 – the `first` item does *not* match, concat the `first` item with the recursive result of the `rest` of the items.

```
const doAThing = (items = []) =>
  isEmpty (items)
    ? []
    : first (items) === 'https'
      ? []
      : [ first (items) ] .concat (doAThing (rest (items)))
```

Ok, so this is exactly how I would like to express `doAThing` – the idea is I just keep *wishing* functions along the way. Now I just need to write `isEmpty`, `first`, and `rest`

```
const isEmpty = (items = []) =>
  items.length === 0

const first = (items = []) =>
  items [0]

const rest = (items = []) =>
  items.slice (1)
```

And allakhazam! Like magic, your program is done. Note, we can collapse the first two cases using `||` because each case returns the same `[]`

```js
const doAThing = (items = []) =>
  isEmpty (items) || first (items) === 'https'
    ? []
    : [ first (items) ] .concat (doAThing (rest (items)))

const isEmpty = (items = []) =>
  items.length === 0

const first = (items = []) =>
  items [0]

const rest = (items = []) =>
  items.slice (1)
    
const data =
  ["check", "out", "my", "blog", "https", "someblog", "com"]
  
console.log (doAThing (data))
// [ 'check', 'out', 'my', 'blog' ]
```

An obvious improvement would be to make the `https` match a parameter of the function

```
const doAThing = (match, items = []) =>
  isEmpty (items) || first (items) === match
    ? []
    : [ first (items) ] .concat (doAThing (match, rest (items)))

console.log (doAThing ('https', data))
// [ 'check', 'out', 'my', 'blog' ]
```

Comment: Thanks but I already know how to do this without a library and how to write JavaScript. Am looking for the best, if any, Lodash method/s that will take those 12 something lines of code and elegantly condense them to 1 or 2, as Lodash does.