# JavaScript Array.concat and push workaround

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

It's always tricky to think `Array.concat` thing. Often, I just want to use mutable `Array.push` because I simply add extra-data on the immutable data. So, I usually do:

```
array[array.length] = newData;
```

I've asked a question related got some answers here: [***How to store data of a functional chain***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279085/how-to-store-data-of-a-functional-chain)

```
const L = (a) => {
  const m = a => (m.list ? m.list : m.list = [])
        .push(a) && m; 
  //use `concat` and refactor needed instead of `push` 
  //that is not immutable
  return m(a); // Object construction!
};

console.log(L);
console.log(L(2));
console.log(L(1)(2)(3))
```

some outputs:

```
{ [Function: m] list: [ 2 ] } 
{ [Function: m] list: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

I feel that `push` should be replaced with using `concat`, but still, `push` makes the code elegant simply because we don't want to prepare another object here.

Basically, I want to do:

```
arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

but, is there any way to write

```
arr1[arr1.length] = arr2;
```

which ends up with a nested array, and does not work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please be clearer.

Comment: `const m = a => (m.list ? m.list : m.list = []).push(a) && m;` That's... quite a confusing line...

Comment: `a.push(...b)` -- do you want this?

Comment: @vibhor1997a -- `arr1[arr1.length] = ...arr2;` -- that's not even a valid syntax.

Comment: @31piy, did you say `a.push(...b)` wasn't a valid syntax?

Comment: It does not work, syntax error @31piy

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a new array with a default array for not given `m.list`.

```js
const L = (a) => {
        const m = a => (m.list = (m.list || []).concat(a), m);
        return m(a);
    };

console.log(L.list);
console.log(L(2).list);
console.log(L(1)(2)(3).list);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still Destructive assignment which I usually never do.

Comment: please add what you want. as i understood the question and some of the comments, you would like to avoid `push`, you want to return an array and you do not like to reassign the array to `list`. why would you like to take a method which returns an array?

Comment: Please read the last 3 lines. Thanks, and I'm doing functional programming, and do not use self-mutating function that is `push`.

Answer (score 0):

`arr1[arr1.length]` represents a single value, the value at index `arr1.length`.

Imagine this array

```
[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]  // arr of length 4
  ^0  ^1  ^2  ^3   // indexes
```

If we say `arr1[arr1.length] = someThing`

We ask javascript to put something right here, and only **here, at index 4**:

```
[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ,   ] // arr of length 4
  ^0  ^1  ^2  ^3  ^4  // add someThing in index 4
```

So, if we want to add something strictly with `arr1[arr1.length]`, then we need to keep doing that for each index. *for each* meaning any kind of loop. E.G:

```js
// Not recommended to use
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [3,4,5];

while (arr2.length){
  arr1[arr1.length] = arr2.shift();
}

console.log(arr1); // [1,2,3,3,4,5]
console.log(arr2); // []
```

But, as you can see, this method, or any similar one, even if optimized, is not the right approach. You need a concatenation.

Since you mention a functional one, which *returns* the resulting array, you can simply replace the initial array and make use of [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [3,4,5];
console.log(arr1 = [...arr1,...arr2]); // [1,2,3,3,4,5]
```

Comment: @Axnyff I hurried indeed. Improved the answer

Comment: @Adelin 　Thank you very much again. I agree with you the spread operator is the best as far as in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple parameters in [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) so:

```
var a = [];
a.push(3, 4) // a is now [3, 4]
```

Combined with the ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
var a = [1, 2];
var b = [3, 4]
a.push(...b); // a is now [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I basically want to avoid to use `push`. simply because it's not a function to return Array. That is the whole point. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do, why do you want to return an array?

Comment: Simply, it's the  functional programming.