# Function call order with the same function as arguments. Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have following code:

```
function f() {

    //...do stuff with arguments 
    //and return something...

}

f(root,
    f(child1),
    f(child2,
        f(subchild1),
        .... 
    ),
);
```

I want to know when the root level of 'f' is called, so I introduce a flag as an argument:

```
f(root, '-r',
  f(child1),
  f(child2),
  //...
)
```

My question is: Is there a way to know when 'f' is called on the top level "f(root,...)" without adding additional arguments?

Comment: You could try the other way around, `F()()()()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51286874/3233388) is an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have no way of telling, in code within `f`, that its return value isn't being used to build an arguments list for a subsequent call to `f`. (Or indeed, that its return value is or isn't being used for any particular thing, or nothing, at all.) It's not an unreasonable question, but that information just isn't available to `f`.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use `f.caller` and check if it's `null`; but it's forbidden in "strict mode" due to tail call optimization: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Also, it would be unreliable for your type of code: ideally, you shouldn't need such type of branching between the `root` and the `children` (see for example any tree structure implementation like the DOM or hyper-script`).

Generally, if you have a `f` function than returns a tree node, it shouldn't matter at what level is called. For example:

```
let subchild = f(subchild1)

f(root,
    f(child1),
    f(child2, subchild),
        .... 
    ),
);
```

That should returns the same structure of your code, but if you will check the caller it won't, since `f(subchild1)` will be the same as `f(root)`.

Comment: *"...but it's forbidden in "strict mode" due to tail call optimization..."* More generally, it's forbidden in strict mode because it's a really bad idea to be assigning the calling function to a property on the called function, not least because while **most** (overwhelmingly) JavaScript environments have only a single thread accessing a given realm, not *all* do, nor is shutting out new multi-threaded environments in the future a spec goal. :-)